# JS preg match instead 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say i have a string:

```
11-34-23|12-67|12-67-87-65
```

And i want to get multiple array like:

```
[['11','34','23'],['12','67'],['12','67','87','65']]
```

Is there any way to create multiple array by regex avoiding FOR loop?

Comment: no RegExp() call outputs an array of arrays, so you NEED to iterate, using for, map, or any other method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain you'll be splitting by pipes and then dashes, then String.split would generate an array, and Array.map would iterate on each part.

For example:

```
"11-34-23|12-67|12-67-87-65"
    .split('|')
    .map(function(item) {  
        return item.split('-'); 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use regular expressions, you can use the `g` (global) modifier to return an array of all the matches.

```js
var result = "11-34-23|12-67|12-67-87-65".match(/[^|]+/g).map(function(item) {
  return item.match(/[^-]+/g);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The first regular expression matches all strings that don't have `|` in them, so it splits the string up using that delimiter. The second regular expression is applied to each of those substrings, and matches anything other than `-`, so it splits the string up using that delimiter.

But it would be clearer if you just used `split`, as in the other answer.